# Solving an inequality involving a floor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Increasing the integer $k$, I can make the floor of $L/k$ smaller than $r$:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{L}{k} \right\rfloor \lt r$$

where $L, k, r$ are positive integers, $k\leq  \lfloor \frac{L}{2} \rfloor$.

Is it possible to write down a "closed form" (or whatever easily computable expression, possibly through low and upper bounds) for **the first integer $k$** where the displayed inequality holds true ?

Comment: The maximum solution of $\frac{L}{K}$ lies in $[(r-1),r)$

Comment: Computable is a strong word to use, you can certainly use bisection to determine the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We  want the first $k$ with $\frac Lk<\lceil r\rceil$, which is the first $k$ with $\frac L{\lceil r\rceil }<k$, i.e.,
$$ k=1+\left\lfloor \frac L{\lceil r\rceil }\right\rfloor$$

*Edit:* I just see that $r$ is an integer, so my writing $\lceil r\rceil$ is unnecessarily cautious, we can simplify to 
$$ k=1+\left\lfloor \frac L{r}\right\rfloor,$$
but note that this is not the same as $\lceil \frac L r\rceil$ because $r$ may be a divisor of $L$.

Comment: Thank you Hagen, very nice. Is it obvious that $\left\lfloor \frac{L}{k} \right\rfloor \lt r$ is the same as $\frac Lk<\lceil r\rceil$ ? Is there a simple way to look at it and "see" that this is true? So in general every time I have $\lfloor x \rfloor < r$ I can just consider: $x<\lceil r\rceil$ ?

Comment: ...or do we need $r$ to be an integer at that very first step too ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that as you increase $k$, $L/k$ decreases monotonically. Thus, the first value $k$ satisfying this inequality satisfies
$$\left\lfloor \frac{L}{k}\right\rfloor <r\le\left\lfloor \frac{L}{k-1}\right\rfloor.$$
Now, since $r$ is a positive integer, this occurs iff
$$ \frac{L}{k} <r\le \frac{L}{k-1}.$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{L}{r}-1< k-1\le \frac{L}{r}.$$
Then since $k-1$ is a positive integer
$$k-1=\left\lfloor\frac{L}{r}\right\rfloor,$$
so
$$k=\left\lfloor\frac{L}{r}\right\rfloor+1.$$

Comment: I'm new to stackexchange, could the downvoter please explain their vote?

Comment: Maybe because you get the wrong $k$ for example when $L=6$ and $r=3$

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I'm editing my answer to correct it. Or is the appropriate action to delete it?

Comment: Thank you. Pretty neat. The fact that r is an integer seems to be quite  useful to obtain a nice solution.